# Can I do 'global Shared Object' in Java?

Tags: java, oop, static, global-variables, memory-address

I have two **CLASS**(each has a thread), and I want to create a queue shared between them. So one class could write some bytes to the queue, and the other can read from the **SAME** queue.

I tried static, and here are my codes:

```
public class ShareQueueTest {
public static final BlockingQueue<byte[]> memshare= new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
public static void main(String[] args){
Thread a = new Thread(){public void run(){
    for(;;){
    try {
        memshare.put(new byte[20]);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(memshare.size());
    }
}};
a.start();
}
}
```

And the other class is simple read from this queue.

```
public class ShareQueueTest2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
Thread a = new Thread(){public void run(){
    for(;;){
        System.out.println(ShareQueueTest.memshare.size());
    }
}};
a.start();
}
}
```

I run it. Though one thread is putting bytes in this queue, the other is still saying the queue is empty all the time. So clearly they are referred to the different things.

ALL the thing happens in local machine.

As this question is simplified from a network scenario, so for some reason, I don't want another class to manipulate those two threads, they are blind to each other. Perhaps the only thing they know for each other is that each thread running on the same local machine, plus, they know the port numbers of the other. Under such condition, I need some methodologies to create a data structure which both of them can 'see'.

I also think of using memory address. Like one class get the memory address of the object, and the other get the object from the address and cast it to the correct data structure. Is it possible in java?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since both of your classes have a main method, it appears that you may be running these two classes in separate processes (instances of the JVM)

If you call ShareQueueTest2.main(...) from ShareQueueTest.main, it should work

Comment: These 2 threads should not be able to see each other. Ideally they should be independent.

Comment: @fTTTTT Here's the thing: only threads in the same process can share memory items. If you need your threads to be process independent, you should think about using a database and/or JMS (Java Messaging)

Comment: So this means, if I want to make these 2 thread share an object, whatever it is, these 2 threads should be AT LEAST, created, in same class?

Comment: Can I understand it as a kind of compiler mechanism somehow? Since compiler read the static keyword and so for those threads compiled at the 'same time' they should refer to the same addr?

Comment: Also if there any other way aspect from using JMS? What about its performance? I try use a shared model since previous theses threads might been deployed in the same machine, and they use network to commnunicate to send some tuples. I hope JMS will be faster than using network connection in two local port.

Comment: @fTTTTT no, and no. But it is too large an answer to explain here. If you are taking a school class, you should ask your professor / teacher.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the two classes separately, it would spawn two separate JVMs which are two separate processes. The thread cannot communicate across processes via a shared queue.

You need to start both the threads from the same code as the other answers point out. Then you can access the shared variables and see the changes done by one thread get reflected in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class ShareQueueTest {
public static final BlockingQueue<byte[]> memshare= new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
public static void subMain(String[] args){
Thread a = new Thread(){public void run(){
    for(;;){
    try {
        memshare.put(new byte[20]);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(memshare.size());
    }
}};
a.start();
}
}

public class ShareQueueTest2 {
public static void subMain(String[] args){
Thread a = new Thread(){public void run(){
    for(;;){
        System.out.println(ShareQueueTest.memshare.size());
    }
}};
a.start();
}
}

public class Launch
{
  public static void main( String[] args)
  {
    ShareQueueTest1.subMain(args);
    ShareQueueTest2.subMain(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: But the key is that these 2 threads should not be able to see each other, neither they should be manipulated by a third party thread by which I mean the method you provided actually use a 3rd party one

Comment: Those threads MUST be manipulated by a 3rd party. They can't launch themselves. In your code each of those 2 threads are also started by a thread different than themselves. Also, what does "not be able to see each other" mean? In your code ShareQueueTest2 is "seeing" the other thread in the line : System.out.println(ShareQueueTest.memshare.size());